# OpenCV C++ - Not able to show a video

Tags: c++, opencv, debian-buster

Linux Debian 10 + OpenCV 320.

Very basic sample to play a video but the application soon ends without open a new window and witout errors.

My tests with same videos but in different types: mp4 and webm. The video are correctly shown by VLC and other video players.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    // check
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage: %s <Video_Path>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Video: %s\n", argv[1]);

    // load video
    VideoCapture cap ( argv[1]);
    if (!cap.isOpened()){
        printf("Error opening video\n");
    }

    Mat frame;
    while(1){
        // cap.read(frame);
        cap >> frame;
          if (frame.empty()){
              printf(".. frame err\n");
              return -1;
          }
        imshow("Live", frame);
        if (waitKey(5)>=0) break;
    }
    printf("end\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
$ ./DisplayVideo 20200313_152914.webm 
Video: 20200313_152914.webm
end
```

Comment: Can you try with just videocapture? Like **VideoCapture cap("ur/video/directory/...webm")** and how it breaks while loop? Do u use keyboard? Or the program does itself?

Comment: I run the program and after a while it ends (let's say less than a second..); I do not use keyboard. As you can see, no errors reported.. I don't understand how and when it exits from the loop.

Comment: Try the code which I suggested, and delete the code before videocapture.

Comment: VideoCapture cap ("/home/stefano/Scrivania/Progetti/visione/showVideo/20200313_152914.webm");
If this is what you mean, the result is the same ..

Comment: Last question: when you tried other video formats(.mp4,.avi etc.) instead of .webm . Does it work or still same?

Comment: mp4 same result :(

Comment: Same with a Camera sample. Now I put a printf() inside the if(waitKey){..} and I discovered that it is printed, so the condition is true and then exit.

Comment: But it should wait a pressing key event from user(you), when I tried it doesnt become true and waits me to press a key. Interesting...

Comment: I printed the waitKey return value and it was 255 - maybe could it be -1 as signed char - so I guess there is a sign problem, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved casting to char:

```
if ((char)(waitKey(1))>=0){
```